# Order Preserving Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering - Python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

Is there any Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering implementation (in Python) available that preserves the order of data points? For example, I want the output something like this.

```
(((seg1, seg2), (seg3, seg4)), seg5)
```

but not like this

```
(((seg1, seg5), (seg2, seg3)), seg4)
```

E.g., **Actual output** with existing implementation
[image: Actual Output with existing implementation]

**Expected output** (any implementation?)
[image]

Comment: Do you realize that this will mess up the clustering graph? For example, `Segment1` and `Segment14` will be placed apart, even though they are hierarchically close. There *may* be a way to present data this way, but the resulting graph will be confusing to say the least.

Comment: @jfaccioni, The above graph is an example. I have a novel (book), and I like to segment it in sequence based on some condition. After that, I want to group contiguous segments based on similarity, and I don't want to group non-contiguous segments.

Comment: Hi @Vijaya - I've reached out to you on LinkedIn and would love to talk about the details of your work on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Vijaya, from what I know, there is only one public library that does order preserving hierarchical clustering ([ophac](https://bitbucket.org/Bakkelund/ophac/wiki/Home)), but that will only return a trivial hierarchy if your data is totally ordered (which is the case with the sections of a book).

There is a theory that may offer a theoretical reply to your answer, but no industry-strength algorithms currently exist: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.04266. I have an implementation of this theory that can deal with up to 20 elements, so if this is interesting, give me a hint, and I will share the code.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, for the information. Yes, I have seen and tried to use "ophac" library. It does not work for my dataset. I have also seen the paper you have mentioned. I had the same intuition before looking at the paper; however, I failed to implement it. It would be great if you could share your code. I can work from there to work for my dataset.

Comment: I made the following repo public:
https://bitbucket.org/Bakkelund/wophac_benchmark/src/master/
The method that implements the clustering is the "hierarchy" method found in the file whophac_approx.py. This is work in progress, and, I must admit, currently not very user friendly. You can see an example of use of this method in src/comparative_analysis.run_wophac(...). In this method, the output is transformed into the same type of output as from the ophac methods.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, for sharing your code. I will take a look at it.